# Link Button File download not works well with firefox

Tags: c#, gridview, download

I have a dynamic Hyper Link in a gridview in asp.net which is used to download the files. When I click that link, IE downloads the file properly with the "C:/Desktop/Files/File.jpg".
But with firefox, the download link appears  with "localhost:XXXX//C:/Desktop/Files/File.jpg"
and throws error in browser 'bad request'

Here's how I render the link:

```
//created a hyperlink on Row data bound// 
HyperLink link = new HyperLink(); 
link.Text = "Download"; 
link.NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl(link to my download file path); 
link.Target = "_blank"; 
e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(link);
```

Comment: You'll need to show some code; how are you generating this download link?

Comment: @ReinderWit //created a hyperlink on Row data bound//
                HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
                link.Text = "Download";
                link.NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl(link to my download file path);                
                link.Target = "_blank";
                e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(link);

Comment: can you give some samples of what 'link to my download file path' will be?

Comment: C:/Desktop/Files/File.jpg

Comment: This file doesn't seem to be part of the website, is that correct? ResolveUrl will try to create the correct path to the file, but that files must, obviously, be available within the website or be placed elsewhere on the internet. The 'relativeUrl' argument should be either a relative or absolute URL, not a filesystem path

Comment: for ex: I mentioned this path. (C:/Desktop/Files/File.jpg )
Actually it is the path on my webserver (networkdrive/filefolder/file) in which my app is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

The [ResolveUrl method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects the 'relativeUrl' argument to be either a relative of absolute URL, not a filesystem path. 
It looks like you're passing it a network location, which is not possible. ResolveUrl will not automagically make files available through the website, it will merely rewrite the given URL to one that's more logical for the client.

For example, it will rewrite something like:

```
../../../Images/logo.jpg
```

to

```
/Images.logo.jpg
```